Jupyter notebook error loading files after I changed the directory. How do I go back to the old path?
I was working on a python file and was very happy with my coding.
I was unable to export it to PDF. When I tried going to the file menu and then download as PDF, I got this error: nbconvert failed: xelatex not found on PATH, if you have not installed xelatex you may need to do so. Find further instructions at https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-tex.
I looked it up on Stackoverflow and saw somewhere that the solution is this command
!export PATH=/Library/TeX/texbin:$PATH

Now I cannot even open Jupiter notebook. getting this error 500 : Internal Server Error
Big problem. Now I cannot even open my files.
Can anyone help?
